# Why the Override() doesnt' work in NHibernate Fluent

Tags: nhibernate, overriding, fluent

I'm trying to set an unique constraint on the column LoginName of table User. So the following is my code:

```
    public FluentConfiguration GetNHConfig()
    {
        var cfg = new FreeflyingConfiguration();
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(_connStr))
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<LogOfArticle>(cfg))
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<LogOfUser>(cfg))
            // here is the problem, I think
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<User>(cfg).UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<UserMappingOverride>())
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Role>(cfg))
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Profile>(cfg))
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Blog>(cfg))
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Comment>(cfg)));
    }


public class UserMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<User>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<User> mapping)
    {
        // breakpoint is set here and can be hit every time
        mapping.Map(x => x.LoginName).Not.Nullable();
        mapping.Map(x => x.Email).Unique();
        mapping.Map(x => x.Profile.BlogUrl).Unique();
    }

}
```

The tables can be generated, and the breakpiont on line "" can be hit every time. But there is no change in database, which means, generate the Unique constraint, whatever I use UpdateSchema() or BuildSchema().

BTW, no error when executing.

So it's harder to find the reason. But any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are `User`, `Role`, `Profile` etc really in different assemblies?  If they aren't you only need one `.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<T>()`.  This could be your problem because it might be overwriting your overrides on subsequent calls.  I'm not all that familiar with overrides but it's worth a shot.

```
return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(_connStr))
        .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings
            .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<User>(cfg)
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<UserMappingOverride>());
```

Comment: all entities are in the same assembiles. But I don't see any difference between your code and mine?

Comment: You have 7 `.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<T>()` and I have 1

Comment: Yes, you're right. But why? it's not operated on Class but assembly?

Comment: It's much easier if it operates on assembly because then you don't have to specify every single class you want to map.